# Set A Column Value in a Multiindexed DataFrame Using One Index and One Column Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas frame with two levels of indexing.

```
                            Class     Score     Mean
Date        Student
2000-01-01  'John Smith'      'A'      92        None
            'Jane Smith'      'A'      82        None
2000-03-01  'John Smith'      'B'      72        None
            'Jane Smith'      'A'      89        None
            'Blackbeard'      'B'      62        None
```

And I want to compare how well each student did relative to the mean. I have a separate function that reads in the average for each class on a given date.

I.e. for 2000-03-01 I'd have something like:

```
Class Mean
 'A'   72
 'B'   68
 'C'   70
```

So what I want to do is set the Mean column for all entries where the index is 2000-03-01 and the Class is 'B' 68.

Without hierarchical indexing this would be really straightforward

```
df.loc[df.['Class'] == 'A'] = 68.
```

What I can't figure out is how to do the equivalent operation with multi-indexing.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `df = df.reset_index()` it will convert your multi-index into regular columns.

Answer (score 1):

First, slice the `"Mean"` column out of the dataframe. Then use Boolean indexing to select the rows you want.

```
df["Mean"].loc[df["Class"] == "A"] = 86
```

In this case the indexing is irrelevant.

Comment: No, you DO need to use ``.loc`` in general. This will ONLY work for a case where the dtype does not change. Since the OP has None in the columns, these are object dtype (which is a separate problem). This WILL show a SettingWithCopy warning if this was correctly dtyped.

Comment: Thank you. Good call, I have removed the offending paragraph and your comment stands as a warning to those who would omit it. I realise that I had already set some rows to numeric values, which is why the warning didn't appear.